# Appending JSON array object to formdata

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have a JSON array object called contacts:

```
var contacts = [];
```

After some processing the value of `contacts` look like:

`[{ "Country":"country 1", "Phone":"123" },{ "Country":"country 2", "Phone":"456" }]`

Now I want to add this to the "Contacts" name inside the formdata. For that I use:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
```

When I try `alert(JSON.stringify(formdata));` on button click I get:

```
\"Contacts\":\"[{\\\"Country\\\":\\\"country 1\\\",\\\"Phone\\\":\\\"123\\\"},
{\\\"Country\\\":\\\"country 2\\\",\\\"Phone\\\":\\\"456\\\"}]\"}"
```

The problem is that in the API, its not detecting the list of contacts.
I tried using POSTMAN as:

```
Contacts[0].Country : country 1
Contacts[0].Phone : 123
Contacts[1].Country : country 2
Contacts[1].Phone : 456
```

API accepts data in that case. API accepts rest of the formdata fields except this, just sharing this info to rule out issue with api.

API accepts a collection of contacts as well as other fields like Name, Age and then Contacts.

Comment: It seems like you're not sending the data as your API expects but you haven't given us any detail about what your API accepts. Also, you've proven that your formdata object has all the info you need, so it's likely not the source of the problem.

Comment: will add reference now. Thanks :)

Comment: Tip: `console.log()` instead of `alert()`.

Comment: @tadman Why? It seems to show the right data?

Comment: What "API"? You need to tell us more about what it's doing, what it expects, and most importantly, how you're sending this.

Comment: @JuanMendes Pop-up alerts are way harder to deal with than console log entries, plus they go away permanently vs. being there for reference.

Comment: @tadman That is true, but it has nothing to do with the question, you should at least have a disclaimer explaining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your API accepts your data in that format, you cannot send it as JSON, you need to create a separate `FormData` entry for each of the lines you've mentioned.

For example

```
const contacts = [{ "Country":"country 1", "Phone":"123" },{ "Country":"country 2", "Phone":"456" }];


var formdata = new FormData();

// This could be made fancier but it explains how to fix the problem
for (let i=0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
   formdata.append(`Contacts[${i}].Country`, contacts[i].Country);
   formdata.append(`Contacts[${i}].Phone`, contacts[i].Phone);
}
```

Note that [json-form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-form-data) does it for you

```js
const data = {
  Contacts: [{
    "Country": "country 1",
    "Phone": "123"
  }, {
    "Country": "country 2",
    "Phone": "456"
  }]
};

const formData = jsonToFormData(data);
for (const [key,value] of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/json-form-data@^1.7.0/dist/jsonToFormData.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Neo Note that I fixed a bug in my initial implementation

Comment: Thanks man. But I am just concerned why a standard practice of code didn't work for me :(

Comment: I don't understand the question, it didn't work because your API didn't support JSON for the Contacts data, it requires this form data encoding style. Note that there's a package that does that for you https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-form-data